# how to create verification authentication besides session/cookie?

Tags: cookies

I want to create authentication on my site, but I know cookie/session is possible to injection by the other person who wants to "hack" our site.

So, do you have any ideas? To solve my problem.

Thanks guys.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588467/how-to-do-stateless-session-less-cookie-less-authentication

Comment: Also here for a general answer on authentication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication/477578#477578